# Find all elements that match a specific ID to the NEXT one

Tags: jquery

Ok, here is the revised question. I apologize for it being poorly put.

What I am trying to do is:

If I toggle() an element, how do I hide any other element that has the same class. 
Here is the JS Fiddle. 
I've tried siblings() and Not() but for some reason, I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<div class="biotitle"> Title One</div>
<div class="bio"> Bio One </div>
<div class="biotitle">Title Two </div>
<div class="bio"> Bio Two</div>
<div class="biotitle">Title Three </div>
<div class="bio">Bio THree </div>
<div class="biotitle"> Title FOUR</div>
<div class="bio">Bio Four </div>
<div class="biotitle">Title Five</div>
<div class="bio"> Bio Five</div>

$(".bio").hide();
$( ".biotitle" ).click(function() {

 $(this).next(".bio").toggle("medium");

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mzt9wqj5/6/

If I add   $(".bio").hide(); before "  $(this).next(".bio").toggle("medium");" it has the desired effect, except if I click on the current element it keeps re-
opening it.

UPDATE:
I think this is the Solution:
 $(this).next(".bio").toggle("medium").siblings(".bio").hide();

Comment: You may want to consider creating a simple http://jsfiddle.net that illustrates your problem. And sharing the link in your queston

Comment: Or not even...sharing just a bit of html might do the trick!

Comment: are you trying to implement an accordion? because jquery ui has a nice one of those.

Comment: Are you trying to close the .bio divs nested under the .bioTitle div clicked?

Comment: `id` is a unique attribute. You cannot have multiple elements with the same id. Did you mean for that to be `class`. If you add unique ids to elements then you can close all other bio divs by using the `:not()` jQuery selector and exclude the element you don't want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the poor explanation, I believe I understand what you are trying to achieve.

I read your question as this:

> How do I toggle the adjacent element's visibility when the previous
>   sibling is clicked?

Firstly, let me start by saying that an `id` attribute is supposed to be unique throughout the document. Elements that share qualities, use the `class` attribute.

So let's look at an amendment to your code. Here's a little CSS for style, a change of markup, and an adjustment to your code:

```js
$('.bio').hide();

$('.biotitle').click( function () {
  
  // get the adjacent bio and show it through show class
  var $adjacent = $(this).next('.bio').toggle('medium');
  
  // get all bio's (except adjacent) and hide all by removing show class
  $('.bio').not($adjacent).hide('medium');
  
});
```

```css
.biotitle {
  padding:20px;
  background:tomato;
  Color:white;
  cursor:pointer
}

.bio {
  background:#333;
  padding:30px;
  color:#eee;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="biotitle"> Title 1 </div>
<div class="bio"> Bio 1 </div>
<div class="biotitle"> Title 2 </div>
<div class="bio"> Bio 2 </div>
<div class="biotitle"> Title 3 </div>
<div class="bio"> Bio 3 </div>
<div class="biotitle"> Title 4 </div>
<div class="bio"> Bio 4 </div>
<div class="biotitle"> Title 5 </div>
<div class="bio"> Bio 5 </div>
```

As you can see, this snippet uses a mixture of CSS style, HTML markup and JAvaScript/jQuery code to achieve what is needed.

***Update***

According to your fiddle, I was correct about what you wanted. The only difference is that I'm using a CSS class to hide/show the attributes, and the CSS styling is slightly different. I have updated my code example to show you what you need.

Click the blue 'Run Code Snippet' button in this answer to see the code in action. I've also updated [your fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mzt9wqj5/9/) to show the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I apologize for the poor explanation. I will create a js Fiddle.